# Start numbering from Page 2 starting with "A"

Tags: microsoft-word

I followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/174505/how-to-omit-the-page-number-from-the-first-page-of-a-word-2013-document-without-using-sections/) tutorial to start numbering from page 2, however I had to set the start numbering value as 0. This works fine in case I'm using Arabic numbers, but in this case I need to number the pages alphabetically "A,B,C,..etc" how can I do that ?

Comment: Little hard to follow exactly what you are asking. Are you asking how to change the format to alphabetic? Or are you saying there is a problem when you use alphabetic characters with the page offset you are using?

Comment: Yes it's the second question, when using the alphabetic characters with page offset, the numbers don't start from A, they start with B as I've removed the numbering from the title page, however i want to start the numbering at A instead. I managed to fix this using Sections

Answer (score 0):

I used the Sections option to separate the title page from the section of pages that using the ABC numbering. I then removed the "Link To Previous" option from the second section to unlink the new section from the title page. Then I formatting the page numbering at Section 2 to "Start at: A"